# Configuring HttpClient in Spring using Basic Authentication

Tags: spring, solr, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm implementing a SOLR server in our application.
We use the CommonsHttpSolrServer in the SolrJ package to connect to our solr server which uses the commons-httpclient.
We also use Spring.

Now our sysadmin secured the solr server (with good reason) and used Basic Auth.

How can I instantiate a HttpClient with Basic Auth to be injected in the SolrJ?

e.g.

```
<bean id="httpSolrServer" class="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer">
    <constructor-arg value="${solrserver_path}" />
    <constructor-arg ref="solrHttpClient" />
</bean>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The interesting bit is the definition of `solrHttpClient`, and you've left that out

Comment: That's exactly the part I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to use a factory that creates the client. There is no bean property for credentials in the classes involved in authentication, namely 
`HttpState.setCredentials(AuthScope, Credentials)` which isn't a bean property.

I uploaded my HttpClientFactory to [github](https://gist.github.com/2487775). Se also the [snippet for the spring context](https://gist.github.com/2487779).